How to create a dynamic url with post title from one website to another?
Since I am new to PHP, i have a question.
I've searched a few days on the internet, but don't really find an answer. I have also tried a few plugin's, but nothing replies to my wish...
What I want to do:
I have two wordpress websites. One is with a product catalog and one, with exact same products is a webshop.
I want to create ONE dynamic link on the productpages on the catalog website which loads the product on the webshop (the second website). Domains are different, but i made shure the product (or post-) titles are exactly the same on both websites.
How do I create one universal URL which then loads post title from source site to the target site?
Example:
https://www.tapverhuuretten-leur.nl/product-a
I put the same link on EVERY product page, under a button, e.g. https://www.deparelevenementenservice.nl/page?name=post_title
Which then loads: https://www.deparelevenementenservice.nl/product-a
With product-b the same must happen, but then the output becomes: https://www.deparelevenementenservice.nl/product-b
In short: I want to create a single link to post on product pages, which then loads the particular product on the other domain with same product (post) title. So product-a is redirected to product a on the second domain. Product-b on catalog site will be linked to product-b on second domain, and so on..
My wish is pretty straightforward, but i think some pretty complex coding is involved?
Ofcourse I can link every product to the second domain manually for every product, but this is very time consuming. Secondly: when i update the products on the catalog site with an import from the webshop, the links will be gone and i then have to set these again.
I have no idea how to programm this. Forgive me if this is a silly question, i'm a beginner. I guess i must code it around the _get_the_title value?
If anyone knows the code, i will be very grateful.
Many thanks for understanding and helping me, in advance.
I have this code available:
    <?php
        woodmart_product_categories();
        woodmart_product_brands_links();
        woodmart_product_sku();
        woodmart_stock_status_after_title();
    ?>
    <?php if ( 0 < $product->get_average_rating() || woodmart_get_opt( 'show_empty_star_rating' ) ) : ?>
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( woodmart_get_product_rating() ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

    <?php if ( woodmart_loop_prop( 'progress_bar' ) ): ?>
        <?php woodmart_stock_progress_bar(); ?>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ( woodmart_loop_prop( 'timer' ) ): ?>
        <?php woodmart_product_sale_countdown( array( 'products_hover' => 'button' ) ); ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php if ( woodmart_loop_prop( 'stretch_product_desktop' ) || woodmart_loop_prop( 'stretch_product_tablet' ) || woodmart_loop_prop( 'stretch_product_mobile' ) ) : ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

Where can I insert the url safely to create the dynamic link (instead of the add to cart button)?

Relatively easy to achieve, just put this somewhere in your template within The Loop:
<a href="https://www.deparelevenementenservice.nl/<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>">Link text</a>


Oh, that is fairly simple indeed! Thank you very much for this information!

I have edited my question, see above. Can you tell me where I can insert the url? I've tried it in another template (woocommerce) but then I get a critical error on the site.
